# Constructive proof for the Hyperplane Separating Theorem (HST)?

Tags: optimization, convex-optimization

HST is usually proven through the existence of a unique minimum-norm vector in a nonempty closed convex set. I think this is an existential proof.

However, to actually apply the result in a real world problem, one might need to find the actual number of the minimum-norm vector through construction.

Do we have a simple constructive proof for HST?

Comment: The merit of the non-constructive proof is that it applies to infinite dimensional Banach spaces as well, where computation may not be possible. However, I agree that specialized proofs over $\mathbb{R}^n$ are often more informative if that's the setting one is working in.